# Animate UIBezierPath arc between 2 angles

Tags: ios, swift, core-animation, uibezierpath, caanimation

I've built a custom circular range picker, similar to the one in iOS's Alarm/Bedtime app. To achieve this, I'm using two `UIButton` *thumbs* with a `UIPanGestureRecognizer` attached and a `CAShapeLayer` + `UIBezierPath` indicating the time-range between them. It works fantastic when I'm using touch input for both movement along the circle and resizing the arc itself.

Pardon my crude depiction of circles, but here's the gist of how the picker works:

[image: Circles]

The **problem** is that I need to switch between certain time-range presets using a `UISegmentedControl` and I'd really wish to animate this change. I've managed to beautifully animate both thumbs *(green)* along the circle in all 360 degrees using `CAKeyframeAnimation(keyPath: "position")`, but I haven't been able to do this with my time-range *(red)* `CAShapeLayer`. The best I managed was animating the range layer using `CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "path")`, but it got distorted during the animation and was not following the arc, but instead went across the circle in a straight vector.

For the sake of brevity, I'll avoid posting the contents of `getStuff()` functions as they're unrelated to the problem.

```
// This works
let startAngle: CGFloat = getAngle(for: start)
let startPath: UIBezierPath = getThumbTravelPath(fromAngle: startThumbAngle, toAngle: startAngle)
let startAnimation = CAKeyframeAnimation(keyPath: "position")
startAnimation.path = startPath.cgPath
startAnimation.isRemovedOnCompletion = false
startAnimation.calculationMode = .cubicPaced
startAnimation.timingFunction = CAMediaTimingFunction(name: .easeInEaseOut)
startAnimation.duration = 0.2
startThumbView.layer.add(startAnimation, forKey: nil)
    
let endAngle: CGFloat = getAngle(for: end)
let endPath: UIBezierPath = getThumbTravelPath(fromAngle: endThumbAngle, toAngle: endAngle)
let endAnimation = CAKeyframeAnimation(keyPath: "position")
endAnimation.path = endPath.cgPath
endAnimation.isRemovedOnCompletion = false
endAnimation.calculationMode = .cubicPaced
endAnimation.timingFunction = CAMediaTimingFunction(name: .easeInEaseOut)
endAnimation.duration = 0.2
endThumbView.layer.add(endAnimation, forKey: nil)

// This doesn't work
let path: UIBezierPath = getRangePathFor(startAngle: startAngle, endAngle: endAngle)
let pathAnimation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "path")
pathAnimation.fromValue = rangePath.cgPath 
pathAnimation.toValue = path.cgPath
pathAnimation.duration = 0.2
pathAnimation.isRemovedOnCompletion = false
pathAnimation.isAdditive = true
rangeLayer.path = path.cgPath
rangeLayer.add(pathAnimation, forKey: nil)
```

I've seen some people suggesting using the `CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "startStroke")` + `CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "endStroke")` approach, but as far as I can tell, this won't work because I can't have a negative value for `startStroke`, thus I can't have an arc stretching from say 270° to 45°.

Comment: Why don't you animate from 270º to 405º?

Comment: The problem is that the `startStroke` & `endStroke` only ranges from 0.0 to 1.0, meaning  I can't go from 0.75 to 1.125

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Looks like `strokeStart` & `strokeEnd` was the answer after all.*

---

### Solution

I managed to solve this by rotating the `rangeLayer` itself in a way that always corresponds the angle of the *start thumb*, so my `strokeStart` is always zero. As the next step, I'm simply subtracting `startAngle` from `endAngle` *(in degrees, not radians)* and using it to calculate the value of `endStroke`.

```
    private func setRangeLayer(startRadian: CGFloat, endRadian: CGFloat, animated: Bool, duration: CFTimeInterval? = nil) {
    let endAngle = endRadian / .pi * 180
    let endStroke = endAngle / 360
    let rotation = CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: startRadian + .pi / 2)
    
    CATransaction.begin()
    if !animated {
        CATransaction.disableActions()
        CATransaction.setAnimationDuration(0)
    } else {
        CATransaction.setAnimationTimingFunction(CAMediaTimingFunction(name: .easeInEaseOut))
        if let duration = duration {
            CATransaction.setAnimationDuration(duration)
        }
     }
    rangeLayer.strokeStart = 0
    rangeLayer.strokeEnd = endStroke
    rangeLayer.setAffineTransform(rotation)
    CATransaction.commit()
    }
```

### Example

The reason I'm converting from degrees to radians and then back to degrees is to standardise the function for different use cases throughout the class. However, you can just as easily use radians for `rotation` and degrees for `endStroke`.

```
    let startAngle: CGFloat = getAngle(for: startTimestamp)
    let endAngle: CGFloat = getAngle(for: endTimestamp)
    let startRadian: CGFloat = (startAngle * .pi / 180) - .pi / 2
    let endRadian: CGFloat = (endAngle - startAngle) * .pi / 180
    setRangeLayer(startRadian: startRadian, endRadian: endRadian, animated: true, duration: animationDuration)
```

### Important note

In order to properly `rotate` `CAShapeLayer` around its center, you **must** set its `frame` / `bounds` beforehand or it will spin along its origin like an airplane rotor instead.

---

Hope this will help someone in a similar situation.